# check if radio button selection against 2 submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of 4 radio buttons with two submit buttons, namely with one's type as "submit" and other's as "button":

```
<form id='myform' method="POST">
    <label style="font-family: sansationregular;">Choose a time frame:</label><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="time" value="t1"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: sansationregular;; vertical-align: middle;"> Today</label> </input>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="t2"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: sansationregular;; vertical-align: middle;"> Last 1 Week</label> </input>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="t3"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: sansationregular;; vertical-align: middle;"> Last 1 Month</label> </input>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="t4"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: sansationregular;; vertical-align: middle;"> Last 1 Year </label></input>
    &nbsp;<br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" class="k" align="middle" id="btn1" value="Download Raw Data" style="font-family: sansationregular; vertical-align: middle;" />
    <input type="button" class="k" id="btn2" value="Most Frequent Words">
  </td>
</form>
```

I have validated the selection of the first button using the following  script:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn2');

form.onsubmit = function() {
  if ($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0) {
    form.action="{{ url_for('choice') }}"
    form.target = '_blank';
  } else {
    alert("Please choose the desired option!");
    form.action="{{ url_for('home') }}"
    form.target='_self'
  }
};
```

However using the same method as above in the next validation didn't work. The below code is where I want to validate if radio buttons selected/not against second submit button.

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  form.target = '_blank';
  form.action="{{ url_for('wordcloud') }}"
  form.submit();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because,

When invoking HTMLFormElement.submit() method directly, no submit event is raised (in particular, the form's **onsubmit** event handler is not run),  and constraint validation is not triggered either.

check out this link for more info, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Alternatively, you can do this. Hope this helps.

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn2');

function inputLength() {
    return $('#myform').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0;
}

function submitForm() {
    if (inputLength()) {
    form.action="{{ url_for('choice') }}"
    form.target = '_blank';
  } else {
    alert("Please choose the desired option!");
    form.action="{{ url_for('home') }}"
    form.target='_self'
  }
}

form.onsubmit = submitForm;

btn.onclick = function() {
  form.target = '_blank';
  form.action="{{ url_for('wordcloud') }}"
  submitForm();
  form.submit();
}
```